# Two equations in align environment with bracket in between

Tags: equations, align, brackets

How can I type such an equation into a LaTeX `align` environment, with a bracket between the two lines of the equation?

[image]

Comment: The mathtools package allows you to use \underbracket, guess that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combination of an `align*` environment, an `\underbrace` instruction, and a fixed-width (centered) parbox get the job done:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\underbrace' macro and 'align*' env.
\newlength\mylen
\newcommand\gterm{{\underbrace{g\langle\bar{\nu}\nu\rangle}}}
\settowidth\mylen{$\gterm$}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} &= \gterm \bar{\nu}\nu \\
            &= \parbox{\mylen}{\hfil$m_{\nu}^2$\hfil} \bar{\nu}\nu
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, my underbrace is not displayed correctly, it is partially black and partially white, not purely black. Is there perhaps a package clash somewhere here? `\documentclass[final,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{IEEE}}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.66,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs, booktabs, multirow}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{exscale}`

Comment: @LCF - Don't load the `exscale` package. Separately, you shouldn't load the `mathptmx` package if you also plan to use the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages.

Comment: @LCF - A follow-up: If you want to use the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages in a `beamer` document, you should also provide the instruction `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the `array` environment for simplicity of syntax and decent spacing with easy access to change the vertical spacing if necessary. Further the default vertical space under `underbrace` isn't too excessive.

```
If $b+c = d$, then
\[
\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} c @{{}+{}} l}
    a & \underbrace{b + c} & e + f\\
      & d                  & e + f.
\end{array}
\]
```

produces

[image: Image showing compiled LaTeX]

Take careful note of the options in the `array` environment to produce proper spacing around `=` and `+`. The `array` environment allows one to specify the alignment of the cells, letting you put `d` in the center of `b+c`.

For your particular example,

```
\[
\begin{array}{r @{{}={}} c @{} l}
    \mathcal{L} & \underbrace{g \langle \bar{\nu} \nu \rangle} & \bar{\nu} \nu\\
                & m_{\nu}^2                                    & \bar{\nu} \nu.
\end{array}
\]
```

would produce the output

[image: Image showing compiled LaTeX]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my code looks simpler and more elegant, but I did copy Mico code for the `\nu` and so on (hehe). And Most part I adapted from [David answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85314/75648).

[image: equation]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{r@{}l@{\,}l}
\mathcal{L}=& \enskip g\langle\bar{\nu}\nu\rangle& \bar{\nu}\nu\\
   & $\upbracefill$&\\
 = & \enskip m_{\nu}^2 & \bar{\nu}\nu \\
  \end{array}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Edit 1- If you add `[-1.5ex]` to the first line of the equation like this:

```
\mathcal{L}=& \enskip g\langle\bar{\nu}\nu\rangle& \bar{\nu}\nu\\[-1.5ex]
```

The difference will be:

[image: negative vertical spacing]

Comment: Can I suggest a negative vspace like `\mathcal{L}=& \enskip g\langle\bar{\nu}\nu\rangle& \bar{\nu}\nu\\[-1.5ex]`

Comment: Sure, i will add both so people can preview the difference.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is the same as Mico's, but the realization is perhaps simpler, with `eqparbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} &= {\underbrace{\eqmakebox[g]{$g\langle\bar{\nu}\nu\rangle$}}}\bar{\nu}\nu \\
            &= \eqmakebox[g][c]{$m_{\nu}^2$} \bar{\nu}\nu
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant for avoiding reentering math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{soO{c}m}
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {%
     \eqmakebox{$\IfBooleanF{#1}{\displaystyle}#4$}%
    }
    {%
     \eqmakebox[#2][#3]{$\IfBooleanF{#1}{\displaystyle}#4$}%
    }%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L} &= {\underbrace{\eqmathbox[g]{g\langle\bar{\nu}\nu\rangle}}}\bar{\nu}\nu \\
            &= \eqmathbox[g]{m_{\nu}^2} \bar{\nu}\nu
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```